# LaTex Error! FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Diego\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Tex\\7f1e3ce1a2acebb7.log'

Tags: python, latex

I'm learning manimlib in python and while running a test script from their own documentation, the following error came up:

```
 LaTeX Error!  Not a worry, it happens to the best of us.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\diego\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\diego\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\anaconda3\Scripts\manimgl.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\diego\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\manimlib\__main__.py", line 17, in main
    scene.run()
  File "c:\users\diego\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 75, in run
    self.construct()
  File "equa.py", line 29, in construct
    Tex("A^2", "+", "B^2", "=", "C^2"),
  File "c:\users\diego\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\manimlib\mobject\svg\tex_mobject.py", line 163, in __init__
    super().__init__(full_string, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\diego\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\manimlib\mobject\svg\tex_mobject.py", line 42, in __init__
    filename = tex_to_svg_file(full_tex)
  File "c:\users\diego\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\manimlib\utils\tex_file_writing.py", line 52, in tex_to_svg_file
    tex_to_svg(tex_file_content, svg_file)
  File "c:\users\diego\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\manimlib\utils\tex_file_writing.py", line 60, in tex_to_svg
    svg_file = dvi_to_svg(tex_to_dvi(tex_file))
  File "c:\users\diego\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\manimlib\utils\tex_file_writing.py", line 94, in tex_to_dvi
    with open(log_file, "r") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Diego\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Tex\\7f1e3ce1a2acebb7.log'
```

But when i go to the following directory:
C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Temp\Tex\7f1e3ce1a2acebb7.log
The file is there

[image]
Can anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: Your screenshot shows `.tex` file,  not `.log`.

Comment: but if you read the tex_to_dvi function of the manimlib libary, the function convert .log to .tex

Comment: It is the opposite. `.tex` is a LaTeX source file. The `.log` file is created when this source file is compiled and contains the log of compilation messages. Normally `.log` file will be created even if the compilation of the `.tex` file fails, but in your case for some reason it does not exist at all. The `tex_to_dvi` function takes a `.tex` file and attempts to compile it. If the compilation fails, it attempts to print the `.log` file to help you see what went wrong. But since you don't have a `.log` file this fails.

Comment: I tried to create a '.log' file but had no sucess

Answer (score 1):

So... after a lot os search and chances, i found a solution, i download the MiKTeX for windows and download all the packages of the program and problem solved!